# Using Filter on Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, radio-button

When using a filter on a radio button, I get an error stating that `.filter` is not a function. As far as I know, selecting radio buttons by name returns an array and I should be able to use filter on an array.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<form action="" name='myForm'>
  <p>Select the Beach</p>
  <input type="checkbox" value='miami' id='miami' name='check'>
  <label for="miami">Miami</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value='florida' id='florida' name='check'>
  <label for="florida">Florida</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value='jamaica' id='jamaica' name='check'>
  <label for="jamaica">Jamaica</label>

  <p>Select the Airline</p>
  <input type="radio" value='american' id='american' name='airline'>
  <label for="american">American</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" value='air india' id='airIndia' name='airline'>
  <label for="airIndia">Air India</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" value='indigo' id='indigo' name='airline'>
  <label for="indigo">Indigo</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Script

```
var myForm=document.myForm;


myForm.addEventListener('submit',getAns);

function getAns(e){
  e.preventDefault()
 var radios=myForm.airline,
     checks=myForm.check;

  console.log(radios);

 var airline= radios.filter(function(val){
    return val.checked;
  });
  console.log(radios);
}
```

Comment: If you look at it properly, the line `console.log(radios);` is logging a json, which has the keys of 0, 1, and so on. So to use .filter, you would need to convert the json to a array.

Comment: *"As far as i know, selecting radio buttons by name returns an array"* - Nope. It's an array-like object, but not an actual array. And @Rishi it is not "a JSON" either: JSON is a string format.

Comment: You could always convert it to an array as well if you wished

Answer (score 2):

It's not an array, but an array-like object.
You can still use filter, but you have to use `call` to make it work.

```
var myForm=document.myForm;
myForm.addEventListener('submit',getAns);

function getAns(e){
  e.preventDefault()
 var radios=myForm.airline,
     checks=myForm.check;

  console.log(radios);

 var airline= [].filter.call(radios, function(val){
    return val.checked;
  });

  console.log(airline);
}
```

EDIT: far clarification, `call` allows you to use methods which were made for other objects or classes, and use them on your own objects. In this case, the filter method is made for arrays, but if you use call, you can use it on a form collection. [Some further documentation here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: Whats the difference between writing
[].filter.call
and
Array.prototype.filter.call

Comment: No tangible difference. The former creates a new empty array which inherits from Array.prototype. Because you never assign the array to a variable, it disappears. [].filter uses Array prototype filter, so you end up using the same function, but with less keystrokes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `myForm.airline` returns an **object**, not an array.

With jQuery, you can get the selected airline with `$("input[name=airline]:checked").val()`:

```js
var myForm = document.myForm;
myForm.addEventListener('submit', getAns);

function getAns(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var radios = myForm.airline;
  var airline = $("input[name=airline]:checked").val()
  console.log(airline);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" name='myForm'>
  <p>Select the Beach</p>
  <input type="checkbox" value='miami' id='miami' name='check'>
  <label for="miami">Miami</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value='florida' id='florida' name='check'>
  <label for="florida">Florida</label>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" value='jamaica' id='jamaica' name='check'>
  <label for="jamaica">Jamaica</label>
  <p>Select the Airline</p>
  <input type="radio" value='american' id='american' name='airline'>
  <label for="american">American</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" value='air india' id='airIndia' name='airline'>
  <label for="airIndia">Air India</label>
  <br>
  <input type="radio" value='indigo' id='indigo' name='airline'>
  <label for="indigo">Indigo</label>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because **filter** is an **array** function

so, so change your code from below

```
var myForm=document.myForm;

myForm.addEventListener('submit',getAns);

function getAns(e){
  e.preventDefault()
 var radios=getFields(),
     checks=myForm.check;

  console.log(radios);

 var airline= radios.filter(function(val){
    return val.checked;
  });
  console.log(airline);
}

function getFields() {
    inputs=myForm.airline;
    var output = [];
    for (var i=0; i < inputs.length ; ++i)
        output.push(inputs[i]);
    return output;
}
```